# Did facebook recently start sending data only compressed in Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, gzip

For some reason this query always returned a standard string (json). For some reason starting today (Jan 24,2014) the results are GZIPped. Easy fix but I was not aware of any changes to the Graph API regarding output. Has anyone else heard of this or is experiencing this?

```
req = urllib2.Request(x)
req = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22are%20eligible%20for%20disability%20compensation%20from%20the%20Department%20of%22&limit=250&type=post&until=1390665731&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxX2HTOgagZDZD&locale=en_US'
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
sys.exit(0)
```

Developer NOTE:  Please do not post access tokens or secret keys in Q and A.

Comment: is your url library sending headers which say you'll accept GZIP encoding?

Answer (score 1):

We were having the same issue. Resolved itself 15 mins ago.